# Rails API versioning, AMS doesn't use custom serializers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, rest, api, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm working on a Rails application and I'm versioning the API.

Following [RailsCast #350](http://railscasts.com/episodes/350-rest-api-versioning) I have this:

`routes.rb`

```
namespace :v1 do         
  #resources for version 1
end

namespace :v2 do
  #resources for version 2
end
```

I use `active_model_serializer` and I have `app/serializers/v1/` and `.../v2/` with:

(for /v1)

```
module V1
  class ResourceSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
      attributes :id
  end
end
```

(for /v2)

```
module V2
  class ResourceSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
      attributes :id, :data
  end
end
```

**But Rails doesn't call my custom serializer.**

```
module V1

  class ResourcesController < ApplicationController

    def show
      @resource = Resource.find(params[:id])
      render json: @resource
    end
  end
end
```

**OUTPUT** for `.../v1/resources/1`

`{"id":1,"name":"...","city":"...","created_at":"...","updated_at":"2..."}`

instead of
`{"id":1}`

**If I put** `render json: @resources, serializer: ResourceSerializer` **it retrieves** `undefined method 'read_attribute_for_serialization'`

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

**EDIT:** Namespaces are valid!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got a solution using `each_serializer: V1::UserSerializer` for `collections` and `serializer: V2::UserSerializer` for normal objects.

Thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

I got this problem also, I have tried many solutions, but didn't work for me

the only solution that works is calling the serializer class directly:

```
  render json: V1::ResourceSerializer.new(@resource)
```

---

If your problem only "undefined method 'read_attribute_for_serialization'", include `ActiveModel::Serialization` into your ActiveModel sub class

```
  module V1
    class ResourceSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
      include ActiveModel::Serialization

      attributes :id
    end
  end
```